# jQuery file upload validation in image width and height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload files. Now in validation I want that my uploaded file size will be under 800 width X 600 height. I have gone through the documentation. But no such help file for this kind of validation is available.Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: "file size will be under 800X600" you mean image i think

Answer (score 0):

In jquery file upload you validate image resolutions till 800x600 or any desired resolutions but you cannot restrict other than 800x600 ,i mean you can validate max-width and max-height

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: change the max-height and max width values in /server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 77,78 from null to 800 and 600,and then try to upload images size more 800 width x 600 height for example 1200 width x 786 height,on upload you will see error message showing exceeded values,but images less than 800 width x 600 height for example 128 width x 96 height no errors will shown